# Should I create a database for every user in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, createuser

My question is: when I create a PostgreSQL user different from the default `postgres` user, should I also create a new database for that user to connect to?

What's the point of a setup like that?

Answer (score 7):

A few explanations:

- Don't use the `postgres` database for user data. It is intended for administrative purposes, for example as a database to connect to if you want to run `CREATE DATABASE`.

  This has nothing to do with users.
- Users are cluster-wide, that is, all databases in a cluster share the same users. Note that that does not imply that every user can connect to each database.
- PostgreSQL command line programs have two defaults:

  - If you don't specify a database user, the default is the database user that is called like the operating system user.
  - If you don't specify a database, the default is the database with the same name as the database user.

I assume that it is this last default that inspires your question.
**This is just a default value and should not influence your database design.**

- Create one database for each separate body of data, like all the data that belong to one application.
- Create users as your application and data maintenance procedures require. It is a good idea to use different users for different tasks. For example, the user that performs the backup should not be used by your application to connect to the database.

Answer (score 1):

No. Even if it's a local admin user so you don't need to go through `sudo`, you should just add `export PGDATABASE=postgres` to your `.bashrc` or `.profile`. I always make a new superuser with the name of my local user, and configure `pg_hba.conf` to allow local connection if necessary.